# how do i get the derivatives of the functions at "a" with out compromising my (x-a) terms any suggestions?

Tags: matlab, function, taylor-series

i need the function to output a  P nth degree taylor polynomial centered at a
here is the code i have , it works almost perfect but  im not sure how to get the derivatives of the functions at "a" with out compromising my (x-a) terms... 
from what i see the diff(f,k) computes the kth derivative of f, but can not plug
in the a. looks my code will require another matlab function that will do the plugging any suggestions?

```
function [P] = mytaylor(f,a,n) 
  f = sym(f);
  syms x;
  terms = 0;
  for k = 0:n
    fk = diff(f,k);
    terms = terms + fk*(x-a)^(k)/factorial(k);   
  end
  P = terms;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `subs` function to evaluate your symbolic expression `fk` at `a`.

Comment: should that go in the for loop or after?

Comment: You have to take the derivative before you can evaluate it. Since `k` changes with your loop (and your therefore your derivative `fk` changes), you need to do it in your loop. I would just change one line to something like `terms = terms + subs(fk,x,a)*(x-a)^(k)/factorial(k);`